# Is city air pollution causes allergy?

Tags: allergy, breathing, air-quality, respiratory-system

- Is there any evidence (study) which shows **correlation** with city air to allergy (to anything) or any other breath health problems?
- If yes is this correlation different if someone lives in big city next to the big water (New York, LA, Chicago)?

PS. Some link to research paper will be helpful. When searching the Internet I only found:

Rodriguez, M. G., Rivera, B. H., Heredia, M. R., Heredia, B. R., & Segovia, R. G. (2019). A study of dust airborne particles collected by vehicular traffic from the atmosphere of southern megalopolis Mexico City. *Environmental Systems Research, 8*(1), 16. https://doi.org/10.1186/s40068-019-0143-3

> Pollen in cities besides being a typical allergen (Kiotseridis et al. 2013) found in the air could also impact health in other ways as it adheres and retains both fine particles and agglomerates.

Comment: People can be allergic to almost anything and it's very individual. Perhaps what you're allergic to is more commonly found in urban areas, or maybe it's not an allergy at all. In any case, we can't tell you what it is or what to do about it. See a doctor.

Comment: I'm not asking about health advice, I'm asking about study about correlation between alergic person (to anything) vs lives in city. I don't asking doctor!!! I thought it clear from my question, if not please suggest your changes to my question, so it will be clear that I'm not interested in health advice here.

Comment: Now it's not asking for advice, but the first version did.  Reopened. However, it still lacks prior research. Have you googled the question? What did you find?

Comment: Related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18653/7951

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link and quote there. Everything needed to understand your question should be in the question itself because comments are subject to deletion at any time and some people don't even bother reading comments.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is and not only allergy: https://www.euronews.com/next/2022/09/12/scientists-finally-discover-how-air-pollution-can-cause-lung-cancer-in-non-smokers

Comment: As discussed in this [main Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), answers on Medical Sciences should be able to stand on their own with links serving as supporting information. Otherwise, answers become useless if the links becomes invalid. Please [edit] your answer to include a reasonable level of detail such that it can be understood on its own.